# Sudden logout from TYPO3 Backend (TYPO3 CMS 8.5.1)

Tags: php, session, typo3, typo3-8.x

Hi TYPO3 CMS Administrators, Editors and Developers.

Recently I encountered some weird behavior in the latest TYPO3 CMS 8.5.1.
Sometimes I suddenly get logged out from the backend. I couldn't figure out any pattern when this occurs.
Sometimes I get logged out when I try to save a page, sometimes it's when saving a TypoScript template, sometimes it happens when I switch from one module to another.
And before you ask: no, it's not the regular session timeout! It happens within minutes after logging in.

So, I'd just like to know if this has happened to someone else or if it's even a known bug in TYPO3 CMS 8.5.1?
If you even know how to get rid of this, or things I should check, I'd appreciate your help! :)

About the Webserver:

- Debian 8.6
- Apache 2.4.10
- PHP 7.0.14
- TYPO3 CMS 8.5.1

Thanks and happy coding

Comment: Maybe this post can give you more insides http://insight.helhum.io/post/143934898030/causes-for-logouts-from-typo3-sessions

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that :)

Comment: Little hint: If you refer to a non-stable version like TYPO3 8.5.1, look if there is a change when going to latest (currently 8.7.9).

Comment: Do you have AWS with scaling?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is go to the install tool and find the lockIP option and replace it with 0. (default 4).

Best regards

Comment: this answer is too general and might loose to much security. If an IP change is the reason for the logout (you need to identify) it might be an option to loosen the IP range from 4 to 3, but a 0 seldom is neccessary.